# Should people with no intention of attempting to answer a correctly phrased question within the guidelines be allowed to vote down based on opinion?

Tags: discussion

Say for a question requires specific and intricate knowledge of a specified program or library, not necessarily in the programming ability, but more the understanding and concept of a task outlined. Should a person who does not have such knowledge be allowed to vote down through their negligence in understanding what the question entails.

For instance asking about the intricate workings of a publicly available (and stated) function from a library where inputs and the function call are included within the question? And if so why?

Comment: Yes.​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Why shouldn't someone with no intention to answer be allowed to downvote? And how do you propose to detect intent?

Comment: @Deduplicator In a request for question clarification at the least.

Comment: Yes. In my estimation the vast majority of downvotes are deserved. They're not cast because of some negligence on the part of the voter, but on the part of the asker.

Comment: How would you differentiate a request for clarification from any old comment? And the first question, which you have not answered yet, is far more important.

Comment: @Deduplicator because although not necessarily clear to everyone, a case specific question should be almost trivial to those using said program. Simply not understanding a question, or it not following your conventional format does not necessarily mean a poorly structured one.

Comment: How do you know that the voter didn't understand your question? Not understanding the reason for the vote doesn't make it illegitimate.

Comment: Let's turn it around: does that mean that people that don't attempt to answer the question can't upvote it, either?  I suspect you wouldn't support that, though, as I'm pretty sure you misunderstand what voting is all about.  It's all about the *content*, and to act as a signal to future readers.  Every time, when someone wants downvotes to be limited, they're not thinking of how it could (and really, should) be applied to upvotes at the same time.

Comment: fbueckbet - no people should be allowed to upvote, downvoting is more malicious

Answer (score 17):

The SO community down votes a question mostly when the question doesn't follow the [standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which can include

- Lack of research - If your question shows no research made by the OP such as linking other posts which were helpful in making progress in solving your problem.
- Lack of effort - If your question shows no effort on your behalf to solve the problem like adding some code written trying to solve to the question.
- Lack of details - If your question is just a code dump and the error with no explanation about the problem, the code or the error.
- Lack of specificity - If your question is too broad like asking how to create a Operating System.
- Lack of [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - If your question doesn't help others to reproduce the problem like not adding a link a fiddle e.g. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or adding relevant code.
- Lack of self-containment - If any of the linked resources are needed to understand the question.

For a member of SO community to figure out the above issues requires very little or no knowledge about a specific program or library and thus they down vote a question to indicate the OP that something is wrong with the question.

Comment: The ironic thing is that you went this far to explain why someone shouldn't have to comment...

Answer (score 9):

I've absolutely no idea about "Node JS". Yet, If I find a question like "Please convert this code to Node JS", I am gonna down-vote it and vote to close.

On SO, rep!=knowledge. So, how are you gonna measure knowledge?. We can have a person with rep of 100 who knows more than a person with rep of 100000.

The current system ensures that people with *a small, yet considerable* amount of reputation are allowed to up-vote / down-vote. This prevents trolls from screwing this place up. So, it makes little sense to measure people (after a minimum rep threshold) based on reputation.

Comment: Are you proposing a change such that rep 1 users can upvote and downvote arbitrary questions and answers? I'd oppose that on the grounds of the easy automated abuse it could lead to. But beyond a very small limit (currently 15 for up and 125 for down) I agree.

Comment: @JonSkeet - No. I have no qualms about the current system. I was merely pointing out *just because a person has less reputation, he should not be considered worthless*.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest you modify your answer slightly, as it seems you don't believe absolutely *everybody* should be able to vote. (And I agree.)

Comment: @JonSkeet - Done :)